# How do I set the left bar button item to be filled in black with a transparent Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

This is what I want.

[image]

This is what I have.

[image: Not quite]

I want the 'X' to be filled in black. How do I do that while at the same time maintaining a transparent navigation bar?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .brown
        
        let mark = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")!

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: mark, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

stop setting leftBarButtonItem tint color to white ie

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
```

and try out these solltins

```
mark.tintColor = .black
```

or

```
let mark = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the tint color to be white, but the 'X' to be filled in black.

Comment: ok . so why don't use "xmark" instead of xmark.circle.fill , and change its tink color to black, and left bar button item background color to white and then add a radius to the left bar button item to make it circular, this will result in a white circle with a black filled cross. Let me know if it works I will edit the answer.

Comment: The background color can't be changed, only the background image. Also, what do you mean by add a radius? leftBarButtonItem doesn't have a radius property...